# Mysql 5.7 query execution visualization (how does mysql decide the execution of query)

Tags: mysql

My queries are running slow with some indexes chosen over others. I am trying to find a tool or a guide using which I can figure out why MySQL decided to give preference to 1 index or 1 table(in case of joins) than others so that I can fine-tune the index or the query.

Till now, I haven't come across an article which explains it in detail or a tool which can provide me with the details of it.

Any inputs will be appreciated. Thanks a ton in advance!

Comment: check [Explain statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/using-explain.html) to see the execution plan of your queries

Comment: Explain is only telling me the index mysql engine used and not answering any why statements

Comment: I haven't yet found any resource on the 'why' part of this. Try turning off `index_merge_intersection` and maybe `block_nested_loop` in the `optimizer_switch` setting. Those two are usually slowing things down. I can't tell whats the actual problem without more specifics.

Comment: According to what I read at other places, index_merge_intersection is useful for a lot of cases while at the same time slows down other places. I have multiple queries and this might impact the overall performance because of which it might not be useful in this case.

Comment: `index_merge_intersection` is *sometimes* useful when you have two indexes `(a) (b)` and don't have a composite index `(a,b)`. Even if turning it off makes some queries slower (which is unlikely), you can add a composite index and fix it. When we migrated to 5.7 we had a few issues with intersection making things worse, and 0 cases where turning it off was a problem.

Comment: [Query Optimization](https://github.com/jynus/query-optimization) is an almost tutorial format of how queries/ indexes are used.

Answer (score 6):

As the Optimizer gets more sophisticated, it gets harder to understand what it is doing.  The latest improvements involve "cost-based" analysis of possible execution methods.  For many queries, it is obvious that one index would be better than another.

There are 4 views into what is going on:

1. `EXPLAIN` is quite limited.  It does not handle `LIMIT` very well, nor does it necessarily say which step uses the filesort, or even if there are multiple filesorts.  In general, the "Rows" column is useful, but in certain situations, it is useless.  Simple rule:  A big number is a bad sign.
2. `EXPLAIN EXTENDED` + `SHOW WARNINGS;` provides the rewritten version of the query.  This does not do a lot.  It does give clues of the distinction between `ON` and `WHERE` in `JOINs`.
3. `EXPLAIN FORMAT=JSON` provide more details into the cost-based analysis and spells out various steps, including filesorts.
4. "Optimizer trace" goes a bit further.  (It is rather tedious to read.)

As for a "visualization", no.  Anyway, `EXPLAIN` and its friends only work with what they have.  That is they do not give clues of "what if you added INDEX(a,b)".  That is what is really needed.  Nor does it effectively point out that you should not "hide an indexed column in a function call".  Example: `WHERE DATE(dt) = '2019-01-23'`.  Note that some 'operators' are effectively function calls.

I've seen a few "graphical Explains", but they seem to be nothing more than boxing up the rows of `EXPLAIN` and drawing lines between them.

I have been struggling with these problems for many years, and have written a partial answer -- namely a "cookbook".  It approaches indexing from the other direction -- explaining what index to add for a given `SELECT`.  Unfortunately, it only works for simpler queries.  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql

I work on a lot of performance questions on this forum in hopes of getting more insight into what to add to the cookbook next.  For now, you can help me by posting your tough query, together with `EXPLAIN SELECT` and `SHOW CREATE TABLE(s)`.

Some random comments:

- "Index merge intersection" is *perhaps always* not as good as a composite index.
- "Index merge union" is almost never used.  You might be able to turn `OR` into `UNION` effectively.
- The newer Optimizer creates an index on the fly for "derived tables" (`JOIN ( SELECT ... )`).  But this is rarely as efficient as rewriting the query to avoid such a subquery when it returns lots of rows.  (Again, none of the `EXPLAINs` will point you this way.)
- Something often forgotten about (but does show up as an unexplained large "Rows"): `COLLATIONs` must match.
- A trick to make use of the PK clustering:  `PRIMARY KEY(foo, id), INDEX(id)`
- Nothing (except experience) says how nearly useless "prefix" indexing is (`INDEX(bar(10))`).
- `FORCE INDEX` is handy for experimenting, but almost always a bad idea for production.
- In a `SELECT` with a `JOIN`, and a `WHERE` that mentions only one of the tables, the Optimizer will *usually* pick the table mentioned in `WHERE` as the first table.  Then it will do a "Nested Loop Join" into the other table(s).

(I should add some of this to my Cookbook.  'Stay tuned'.  Update:  Done.)